# Default merge tool used in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, tfs, merge, diff

In TFS 2008 and visual studio there exists diffmerge.exe which is used to merge as a default merge tool in TFS. But what is the exe used in TFS 2012?

I have changed parameters to diffmerge.exe in setting as mentioned in this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b1673bfe-b67c-4dc3-886d-e99da97c37a7/source-control-compare-compare-options) for my convienient. I wanted to do same in visual studio 2012.But i didnt find diffmerge.exe itself. So what is the default merge tool used in visual studio 2012?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TFS 2012 built a new diff/merge experience based on the VS editor. See:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/08/31/merge-enhancements-in-tfs-11.aspx

I got this information from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d1f25833-8271-47ed-bcd9-5cee5cf687d7/default-merge-tool-used-in-visual-studio-2012?forum=tfsgeneral)